# Explain Sun Glare

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, diffraction, camera

[image: Sunset on the road]

Above is a picture that I took just before the sun set. Notice the prominent red blob to the left of the sun. Can anyone explain the phenomenon that creates superimposed shapes and blobs in images of the sun and other light sources, like the one above? A diagram would be much appreciated.

Comment: Internal reflections inside the camera lenses. The shape of these things depends on the detailed construction of the lens. Some lenses produce more artistic looking lens flare (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare) than others and are used by photographers specifically to get this "effect" (which is really a near unavoidable technical flaw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for these is mostly reflection inside the optics of the camera, both from the surfaces of the lens elements and from the structure of the lens body, diaphragm, camera body and so on.

There can be other reasons for artifacts like this: diffraction effects when the lens is stopped right down and effects due to light bouncing around inside the film or sensor, as well as (nowadays) saturation effects in sensors which can lead to odd effects.

One interesting thing about lens flare like this is that *it's always there*: the lens does not particularly care that it is looking at the Sun (the sensor probably does), but stray light bounces around regardless. You only really notice it like this when there is a hugely bright object -- normally the Sun -- either in the picture or just outside it, and you notice it then because the reflections become as bright as the rest of the image.  The rest of the time the reflections are not easily seen, but they serve to reduce contrast in the image as light 'leaks' from bright areas to darker ones.

Modern lens designs and coatings are hugely more flare-resistant than older ones.  People like me often seek out older lenses for their 'glow' which is, of course, just flare of variois kinds.

Comment: Why don't I see lens flare with my naked eye? Can't we design lenses more like eyes, so we don't have to deal with lens flare?

Comment: @KevinK. That's a good question, and I don't know the answer.  My suspicion is two related things: firstly that eyes deliver reasonable image quality in only a tiny central area (the point we are looking at) which allows a lot of compromises which a camera lens can't make; and secondly that our visual system just lies to us, and there probably *is* flare which it is suppressing.  But I don't know.